# How can NPM scripts use my current working directory (when in nested subfolder)

Tags: yo, npm-scripts, pwd

It's good that I can run NPM scripts not only from the project root but also from the subfolders. However, with constraint that it can't tell my current working path ($PWD).

**Let's say there's a command like this:**

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "pwd": "echo $PWD"
}
```

If I run `npm run pwd` within a subfolder of the project root (e.g, `$PROJECT_ROOT/src/nested/dir`), instead of printing out my current path `$PROJECT_ROOT/src/nested/dir`, it always gives `$PROJECT_ROOT` back. Are there any way to tell NPM scripts to use my current working directory instead of resolving to where *package.json* resides?

<sub>Basically I want to pull a Yeoman generator into an existing project and use it through NPM scripts so that everyone can use the shared knowledge (e.g, `npm run generator`) instead of learning anything Yeoman specific (e.g `npm i yo -g; yo generator`). As the generator generates files based on current working path, while NPM scripts always resolves to the project root, I can't use the generator where it intend to be used.</sub>

Answer (score 42):

> If you want your script to use different behavior based on what subdirectory you’re in, you can use the `INIT_CWD` environment variable, which holds the full path you were in when you ran `npm run`.

Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

Use it like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "live-server $INIT_CWD/somedir --port=8080 --no-browser"
}
```

**Update 2019-11-19**

`$INIT_CWD` only works on *nix-like platforms. Windows would need `%INIT_CWD%`. Kind of disappointing that Node.js doesn't abstract this for us. Solution: use `cross-env-shell live-server $INIT_CWD/somedir....` -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Answer (score 2):

One known solution is through ENV variable injection.

For example:

Define scripts in package.json:

`"pwd": "cd $VAR && echo $PWD"`

Call it from anywhere sub directories:

`VAR=$(pwd) npm run pwd`

However, this looks really ugly, are there any cleaner/better solutions?

Comment: +1 because im trying to do the same and arrived at doing the same.  Seems like a feature that ought to be built in to npm scripts.  i dont want to have to add a whole dependency just to type 4 letters for me.

Answer (score 1):

With node 8+ you can automate the ENV variable injection.

1.- In $HOME/.node_modules/ (a default node search path) create a file `mystart` with

```
process.env.ORIGPWD = process.env.PWD
```

2.- Then in your $HOME/.bashrc tell node to load `mystart` every time

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="-r mystart"
```

3.- Use `$ORIGPWD` in your scripts. That works for `npm`, `yarn` and others.